# How to do I get a random ranged number of items from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, random

I'm using the code below to get a random number of items from an array, but I'd like to just get 3-5 random numbers from the provided range to display. Right now, it either shows 1, all, or any amount in between. I'm also good with completely changing up my strategy, so any and all advice is welcome. Much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fiftyallstars.com/Code/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('div').filter(function(){
    return (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1);
}).css({display: 'none'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1:** Shuffle the array

**STEP 2:** Randomly pick a number b/w 3 to 5.

**STEP 3:** From the beginning (or end) of the shuffled array pick random number of elements.

```js
const arr = ["apple", "mango", "banana", "grape", "orange", "guava", "melon", "watermelon"];

const shuffledArr = arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

const getRandom = (arr, min, max) => {
  const numItemsToPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min
  return arr.slice(0, numItemsToPick)
}

const randomArr = getRandom(shuffledArr, 3,5)
console.log(randomArr)
```

Comment: The snippet works, but I can't get the code to work elsewhere. Should I be referencing a library in the <head> section or something? All I've done so far is add the `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` tags around what you've provided, but still everything is blank. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: @JonSanders The code is written in plain vanilla JS, no libraries involved. The code I gave above is working with the array of fruits, you need modify it to work with `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ar = $('div'); //  get all the divs 
let start = Math.round(Math.random()*ar.length); // get random start 
let end = Math.round(Math.random()*ar.length); // get random end 

ar.splice(start,end).forEach(item=>{  // for getting random elements 
    item.style.display='none'
})
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add some explanation as to why this code is different then the other answer?